# why does R subset fail silently when I use single equals

Tags: r

I made this rookie mistake in R

```
subset(mtcars, cyl = 4)
```

with single equals `=` instead of double equals `==`

Why does it fail silently, i.e., return the unfiltered list, instead of breaking with an error?

Comment: try that with `[`: `mtcars[mtcars$cyl = 4, ]`.. IMO the rookie mistake was using `subset` :) I think everyone has been there

Comment: It doesn't **fail** -- it does exactly what you told it to do.  Software is like that.

Comment: what's wrong with subset?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What's actually happening is that `cyl = 4` is being treated as an additional **named** argument passed on to `...` in `subset.data.frame`, and so there actually is no `subset` argument to filter with.

As for why it is programmed in such a way as to not throw an error in this case, you'd have to ask R Core for the *real* answer. But based on how R does it's function argument matching, it seems like it would be a hard thing to detect. Or at least, awkward.

For instance, what if a package implemented a new S3 method for `subset` that had an actual additional argument called `cyl`?

Comment: @ZiyaoWei It was only a hunch on my part until I stepped through `subset.data.frame` to double check.